# Open source software - create short avi - random words, changing text characters

Tags: text, video, open-source

Is there an open source software package I can use to create a short video, like the one in this link?

https://www.akamai.com/uk/en/multimedia/videos/unified-security-header-video-v3.mp4

The video has words which change and letters which also change, fading in and out to end with a complete, unfaded sentence.

I am guessing I need multiple text layers and the ability to edit the text, individual characters and change the opacity of individual characters.

I am unsure what this type of animation (changing words and letters) is called.  It's almost like a 'cipher' video, though not exactly.

Is there an open source package I can use?

Answer (score 1):

[**Natron**](https://natron.fr/) could get this done well - it's an open-source feature-film-quality compositor, nodally based and can use Nuke plugins. You could also look at [**DaVinci Resolve**](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve/).

Answer (score 0):

One option is that you look for a JavaScript text generator, and capture the output on your browser using OBS obsproject.com